# vNet integration fo app services using ARM Template

Tags: azure, templates, cloud, azure-resource-manager

I was trying to add a subnet in azure app service using below logic but it not working , if condtion is working fine but resourceId i snot forming right id for subnet and not connecting the subnet can some one help me to fix this , i have around 10 app service in azure some of them are demanding Subnets needed to be add so that using if condition and if the app service name match to appapi then need to add subnet called subpceus2report with that please give me suggestion for it

```
"virtualNetworkSubnetId": "[if(contains(variables('appCopyArray')[copyIndex('appCopy')], 'appapi'), resourceId('rgppceus2', 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets','vntpceus2', 'subpceus2report'), '')]"
```

Need to add subnets to app services

Answer (score 0):

- There appears to be a syntax error in the expression you gave for the `virtualNetworkSubnetId`. Here is an improved version to avoid the error.

```
"virtualNetworkSubnetId": "[if(contains(variables('appCopyArray')[copyIndex('appCopy')], 'appapi'), resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'vntpceus2', 'subpceus2report'), '')]"
```

- **rgppceus2** is not necessary for specifying the subnet resource ID. The `resourceId` function should be used to construct the resource ID in the format `'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets'`.

Here I have tried in my way according to your requirement check the  below code :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "appName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Azure App Service."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "subnetId": "[if(contains(parameters('appName'), 'appapi'), resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'vnetIntegration', 'mysub01'), json('null'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('appName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('appName')]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "virtualNetworkConnection": [
            {
              "name": "vnetIntegration",
              "properties": {
                "vnetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'vnetIntegration')]",
                "subnetResourceId": "[if(not(equals(variables('subnetId'), json('null'))), variables('subnetId'), json('null'))]"
              },
              "condition": "[not(equals(variables('subnetId'), json('null')))]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Deployment status :**
[image]

**Output :**
[image]